# Oidc Client Sign in with Username and password

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have a login form which have username and password fields in it. **I want to authenticate username and password with Oidc Client** . This is a method that was used for signing in by default:

```
     async signIn(state) {
            await this.ensureUserManagerInitialized();
            try {
                const silentUser = await this.userManager.signinSilent(this.createArguments());
                this.updateState(silentUser);
                return this.success(state);
            } catch (silentError) {
                // User might not be authenticated, fallback to popup authentication
                console.log("Silent authentication error: ", silentError);

                try {
                    if (this._popUpDisabled) {
                        throw new Error('Popup disabled. Change \'AuthorizeService.js:AuthorizeService._popupDisabled\' to false to enable it.')
                    }

                    const popUpUser = await this.userManager.signinPopup(this.createArguments());
                    this.updateState(popUpUser);
                    return this.success(state);
                } catch (popUpError) {
                    if (popUpError.message === "Popup window closed") {
                        // The user explicitly cancelled the login action by closing an opened popup.
                        return this.error("The user closed the window.");
                    } else if (!this._popUpDisabled) {
                        console.log("Popup authentication error: ", popUpError);
                    }

                    // PopUps might be blocked by the user, fallback to redirect
                    try {
                        await this.userManager.signinRedirect(this.createArguments(state));
                        return this.redirect();
                    } catch (redirectError) {
                        console.log("Redirect authentication error: ", redirectError);
                        return this.error(redirectError);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Method was called from **Login.js** :

```
async login(returnUrl) {
        const state = {returnUrl };
        const result = await authService.signIn(state);
        switch (result.status) {
            case AuthenticationResultStatus.Redirect:
                break;
            case AuthenticationResultStatus.Success:
                await this.navigateToReturnUrl(returnUrl);
                break;
            case AuthenticationResultStatus.Fail:
                this.setState({ message: result.message });
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error(`Invalid status result ${result.status}.`);
        }
    }
```

Now i have a custom login form. I will have value of user-entered username and password but I have no idea of authenticating it. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not supported by the library yet.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/234